# Angular2 create array from another array

Tags: arrays, angular5

Hi I am developing AngularJS 2 application. I am trying to create new array from existing array. I have my below array.

```
[
   {
      "roleid":"666c01aa-5272-40bc-a888-5edac9087aad",
      "ischecked":"false",
      "rolename":"Observer",
      "tenantid":"3a8360d6-9491-4191-a1ea-3260b70c3cd2",
      "isactive":true,
      "isdeleted":false,
      "scopeids":null,
      "scopes":null
   },
   {
      "roleid":"4df4bf2f-16b0-482a-84c1-7a646bbfcf71",
      "ischecked":"true",
      "rolename":"Operator",
      "tenantid":"3a8360d6-9491-4191-a1ea-3260b70c3cd2",
      "isactive":true,
      "isdeleted":false,
      "scopeids":null,
      "scopes":null
   }
]
```

I have one more array `dropdownList = [];`
In the first array i have properties roleid and rolename. I want to reproduce my first array into as below.

```
  this.dropdownList = [
  {"id":666c01aa-5272-40bc-a888-5edac9087aad,"itemName":"Observer"},
  {"id":4df4bf2f-16b0-482a-84c1-7a646bbfcf71,"itemName":"Operator"}
                      ]
```

I want to copy roleid and roename into id and itemName in dropdownList array. 
I tried as below.

```
var id, itemName;
        results.forEach(eachObj => {
            this.dropdownList.push(
                id = eachObj.roleid,
                itemName = eachObj.rolename);
        });
```

Here result is my first array. I am looping through each row and pushing to dropdownList. This results in sequence of rows starting from index 0 but i wanted as i shown above. Can someone help me to make this works? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if i really understant what do you want, but lets go! You need encapsule the object.

```
results.forEach( eachObj => {
    this.dropdownList.push({
        id :  eachObj.roleid,
        itemName : eachObj.rolename
    });
});
```